# android send and receive TCP Package

Tags: java, android, sockets, package

I just got a quick question.
I'm  trying to make an app that can communicate with a server by sending TCP packages and then the server sends a TCP package back or to other device.
But how can I make a service that when a TCP package has been received on the device that it makes an notification?

I tried this;

```
 extends Service {
Thread henk;

private static final String TAG = "Service";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    henk = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Boolean end = false;
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1337);
                while(!end){
                        //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                        Socket s = ss.accept();
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                        String st = input.readLine();
                        Log.d("Tcp Example", "From client: "+st);

                        s.close();

                }
        ss.close();


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }



    });


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    henk.run();

}
```

But that just crashes my app. 
Help please?

Stack Traces:

```
    E/ActivityManager(  240): ANR in tictactoe.elqauto
E/ActivityManager(  240): Reason: Executing service tictactoe.elqauto/.servicere
cieve
E/ActivityManager(  240): Load: 7.09 / 7.29 / 7.5
E/ActivityManager(  240): CPU usage from 9411ms to 3791ms ago:
E/ActivityManager(  240):   1.2% 3857/de.devmil.minimaltext: 1.1% user + 0.1% ke
rnel / faults: 191 minor
E/ActivityManager(  240):   2.5% 240/system_server: 1.9% user + 0.5% kernel / fa
ults: 20 minor
E/ActivityManager(  240):   0.1% 4797/tiwlan_wq: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  240):   0% 16322/org.adwfreak.launcher: 0% user + 0% kernel
/ faults: 226 minor 1 major
E/ActivityManager(  240):   0% 19108/com.aricent.mtp: 0% user + 0% kernel / faul
ts: 16 minor
E/ActivityManager(  240):   0% 30600/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kern
el / faults: 20 minor 5 major
E/ActivityManager(  240): 11% TOTAL: 8% user + 3% kernel + 0.1% iowait
E/ActivityManager(  240): CPU usage from 368ms to 884ms later:
E/ActivityManager(  240):   5.6% 240/system_server: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel / fa
ults: 15 minor
E/ActivityManager(  240):     5.6% 266/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  240): 44% TOTAL: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel + 40% iowait
```

**Summary:**

So what I'm trying to do is send a TCP package with a name to the server the server will get the IP that belongs with that name from the Database and send a TCP package to it with some info. Since I didn't find a solution I tried sockets but now I'm stuck on the receiving part.

Comment: Have you used logcat? If you can, post the stack trace from logcat when your app crashes: `adb logcat -s *:E` should do it in the command line. My guess there's an attempt to update the UI from not the UI thread, but the crash output will tell for sure.

Comment: @jarvisteve Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' But i cant find that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It do not make much sense to run a TCP server on the android device as you usually do not know its address.

An alternative solution is to keep a client connection alive to the server and then push packages back to the what ever devices that should receive the package.

A more battery efficient solution is to use Google's C2DM. This do however require the devices to be logged in with an Google account.

Comment: Well i send my IP when changed to a Database and the server gets the name i want to sent it to with the ip and sends the package to that device but it needs to be recvieved can C2DM even do that?

Comment: What should happen if the recipient is offline? Should the transfer fail or should the package arrive eventually when the recipient gets online? C2DM is intended to solve the last case, but could also be use to implement the first if latency is a concern. You would have to describe your communication scenario in more details for me to comment more on this.

Comment: When he gets back online he will receive it thats what im also trying. wait i'll edit it

Comment: C2DM is android answer to iphones push notifications. You will have a hard time implementing this yourself and most likely also consume way more batty power. [link](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) explains it in more details.

Comment: In any case. You cannot keep a welcome socket reachable on, say port 1337, on the devices on anything but you own network. I think you will have to do periodic polling or to keep a client connection alive to do long polling if not using C2DM.

Comment: I get that but how can i send that when mobile A did something it sends it to mobile B without draining battery like polling and C2DM needs and Google account authentication

Comment: Not having a server running on a phone, you will need to have one elsewhere. When pushing a message from A to B, A send the message to the server where it is store until B ask the server for new messages. B may ask periodically or use long-polling, depending on the responsiveness demands. I can only imagine that C2DM does the same, the benefit from using it is that all connections share the same polling connection. I do not know how much energy it takes to do it again yourself.